# Gcc /usr/bin/ld compiler error

Tags: gcc, compilation, ld

I got this error when I do make

```
 gcc -o tests/simple_test tests/simple_test.o -L. libtraceback.a -Wall -Werror -gdwarf-2 -O0 -m32 -fno-stack-protector -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Itraceback/ -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2   -static
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_eh
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I read one post and tried

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib64
```

But it doesn't help, is there any reason for this?

Im running on a surface pro 2 using vmware running 64bits ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Looks like your compiler is misconfigured. I would try reinstalling it.

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc

Comment: I got the same error after reinstall

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a 32bit piece of code and it's only looking at 6bit libraries - the `-m32` indicates this. At a guess you're missing the 32bit libraries. If you're really trying to make 32bit code, then you'll need to make sure that you have the relevant 32bit libraries installed. Last time I did this the command needed was `apt-get install ia32-libs`

Comment: That make sense, do I have to change the Makefile or anything?

Comment: I got this message "This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0"

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have any parcticular reason to build a 32bit application on a 64bit machine just do not use the option `-m32`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are following [this](https://dev.to/frosnerd/writing-my-own-boot-loader-3mld#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20switch%20to%2032%20bit%20protected%20mode%20so,in%20the%20control%20register%20cr0%20.) tutorial then fixed make file code is below working on Ubuntu 20

```
# $@ = target file
# $< = first dependency
# $^ = all dependencies

# First rule is the one executed when no parameters are fed to the Makefile
all: run

kernel.bin: kernel-entry.o kernel.o
    ld -m elf_i386 -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary --entry main

kernel-entry.o: kernel-entry.asm
    nasm $< -f elf -o $@

kernel.o: kernel.c
    gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@ -fno-pie

mbr.bin: mbr.asm
    nasm $< -f bin -o $@

os-image.bin: mbr.bin kernel.bin
    cat $^ > $@

run: os-image.bin
    qemu-system-i386 -fda $<

clean:
    $(RM) *.bin *.o *.dis
```

To run make file

```
make run
```

to clean all output files

```
make clean
```